# Subtracting time from current time in R

Tags: r

I am designing a flex dashboard for my office.
I have a column( lets say Entry time) containing time stamp(ex-2020-06-01 20:30).I want to remove those rows for which the diff between current time and entry time is greater than 24 hours. Can u please help ?

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example and expected output please? Also your attempt that failed

Answer (score 0):

If you are `tidyverse` person you can do so using `lubridate` and filter pretty easily and then `select` to keep the columns you want after filtering.

```
require(lubridate)
require(tidyverse)
df <- df%>%
     mutate(time_difference = interval(ymd_hm(start_column), ymd_hm(end_column))%>%
     filter(as.numeric(time_length(time_difference, 'hour')) >24)%>%
     select(-time_difference)
```

This takes a `dataframe`, creates a new column with a `lubridate` interval in it. Then uses time length to get the duration in hours, which is coerced to numeric (just in case as some date objects are strings under the hood) within a filter to select times less than 24 hours. The last row using `select` simply removes the `time_difference` field created to do the filtering.

This will all be saved back into the original dataframe.

Just check the grammar before you go. Without code to test it on, I may have missed a closing parenthesis or something somewhere~